# assessing whether ec2 t3.nano instance can handle workload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I currently have an ec2 t2.micro instance and rds db.t3.micro instance on AWS, and in order to reduce costs I wish to transfer both the application (which is currently on the t2.micro ec2 instance) and database onto t3.nano or t3.micro instances. Thus my question is how do I analyse my current infrastructure in order to determine whether or not t3.nano/micro instances can handle the workload that my previous instances are handling? Do I look at the CPU percentage or something else? The CPU for my RDS is showing 4.75% at the moment - can I take this to mean my rds is using very little and thus could probably be shifted to something smaller?

Comment: Try to use metric service like cloudwatch ,it will help you in monitoring general performance for your application or workload as well as alerting you on computing resouces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that T2 and T3 are [Burstable performance instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html) meaning that they are very powerful if used in bursts, but provide lower performance when usage is sustained.

So, if your system becomes popular and has a continual load, the app/database might suddenly drop in performance when the burst credits run out. This won't be obvious with normal monitoring, which would show everything performing very when there are only occasional bursts of traffic.

Reducing the instance size will also reduce memory, which could cause problems with your app/database.

If you just have a simple app & database requirement, you could consider using Amazon Lightsail, which can offer considerable savings since it includes a free bandwidth allowance.

Comment: I have a node js application (with plain html/css front end) and a MySQL database. Would it be reasonable to put each on the smallest linux instance in lightsail for a total of $7/month ($3.50 each)? My database only has 14 tables and none of them exceed 10000 rows. My priority is minimising costs so I’m willing to put the database on ec2 over rds as long as the application works the same, and i can manually export the database to take backups

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but the only way to know for sure is to try it! It would be good if you can simulate normal traffic load, or simply keep an eye on it while in Production and respond if the system performs poorly.